# Encode all characters to entities

Tags: php, email, encode

I would like to convert all characters to character entities to act as a spam protection for email address. I need entities in this format

```
&#121; &#111; &#117; ...
```

just like on this web (here done by JS):

[character entities encoding](http://www.wbwip.com/wbw/emailencoder.html)

Is there any simple way to do that in PHP like with built-in functions?

Answer (score 0):

```
function encode2($str) {
    $str = mb_convert_encoding($str , 'UTF-32', 'UTF-8');
    $t = unpack("N*", $str);
    $t = array_map(function($n) { return "&#$n;"; }, $t);
    return implode("", $t);
}
```

> or

```
function encode($str) {
    $str = mb_convert_encoding($str , 'UTF-32', 'UTF-8'); //big endian
    $split = str_split($str, 4);

    $res = "";
    foreach ($split as $c) {
        $cur = 0;
        for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
            $cur |= ord($c[$i]) << (8*(3 - $i));
        }
        $res .= "&#" . $cur . ";";
    }
    return $res;
}
```

Comment: Not quite sure this is what OP was looking for. That linked example convert all the characters, even letters.